# This Site Can't be Reached Error while trying to Run the Dash App locally in Chrome Browser

Tags: python, plotly-dash

When I'm trying to run locally a sample dash app code but I'm always getting an error of this site cant be reached. From other threads i came to know this error can be solved by doing some settings in chrome browser.

I'm using Jupyter Notebook and running the below sample code for my learnings.

```
# Run this app with `python app.py` and
# visit http://127.0.0.1:8050/ in your web browser.

from dash import Dash, html, dcc
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

app = Dash(__name__)

# assume you have a "long-form" data frame
# see https://plotly.com/python/px-arguments/ for more options
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Fruit": ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas"],
    "Amount": [4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5],
    "City": ["SF", "SF", "SF", "Montreal", "Montreal", "Montreal"]
})

fig = px.bar(df, x="Fruit", y="Amount", color="City", barmode="group")

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for your data.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure=fig
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I am tring to access on this link:
http://127.0.0.1:8050/

I am still getting the error. I have no doubt on code because it is just copied from the dash official website

https://dash.plotly.com/layout